# How can I check if an API token is still valid

Tags: javascript, php, api, token

I'm using a token for my API, the problem is that *when the token is invalid* (time to live < 0) there's no way to know it, so you go on and fill out a form and only when you submit it you get the message "invalid token" which is really annoyin. My idea is to write a script that checks the token's time to live every 10sec for example and then if it's invalid I can disable the forms for example or display a box to force the user to reload the page. Maybe you guys have better ideas , so please don't hesitate to share.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you need such a short-lived token? Why not issue out relatively long lived tokens? I mean, if they die out often, you might have to set the token life a bit longer to allow the filling of the form.

Comment: Some pages do what you say; they pop up a message asking to refresh, but I don't think that's cool. Ideally the token should be long enough to do a few tasks, but disallow tasks submitted after a 'long' time. What kind of an access token have you designed for your API?

Comment: @Aravind I agree with you the token should be long enough, it lives now for one hour, but the problem is that the clients may keep the page open for more then one hour, and it's also not in my hand to change the API's time to live, because I'm just consuming it, and it's there for security reasons.

Comment: Right, then, is your concern that once the form is submitted, the content entered is lost and they would have to re-enter all the information? Or is your concern that they would have to login again(renew the access token)?

Comment: Also, I thought this was your API, which specific API are you talking about? Maybe there is a way in that API to swap a short-lived token with a long lived token. Facebook has this swap possible via an API call.

Comment: My concern is to check the token's life before the client submits the form, even before he starts typping, maybe i will use an Ajax request when any input gets focus or on key down, or if it is possible to make a timer of one hour when the page is loaded and alert the client when the time is up. The API is ours yes, but I'm not allowed to modify it yet. thanks @Aravind.

Comment: The Timer is not a reliable way to do this. The reason is because  with both setTimeout and setInterval, the functions are not called after 't' ms. Instead the function specified in the timer is added to the end of event queue, so suppose the user is doing some other javascript tasks, our function may run after a long long time. A better way is to target the events of entry and exit of fields.

Comment: What happens currently when you submit form with an invalid access token? How are you handing the data entered in the form?

Comment: @Aravind thanks for your time, well currently, when the user submits the form and the server checks the token, it returns a message saying that the token is invalid, so I guess maybe redirecting with the a new token and the same inputs will be fine, or you think that it's best to prevent the user before filling the form ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in a very simple way, I would guess you have an "expiration time" set on your server side for your token. You can just return this time and have a JS function check that value every x seconds or on every required action (open a pop/form/etc).

Probably when you return the token your json can look something like

```
{
    token:"1234567890",
    expire: "1427484624" //timestamp in seconds, easier to compare
}
```

Then your JS function can be something as simple as:

```
function isValidToken(token){
    cTs=Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
    return (token>=cTs);
}
```

and that way you can know very easily.